# How to delete entire row if only last cell contain data

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA excel macro programming and currently writing a code to delete entire row if only last cell contains data for example if cell A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 are empty and H1 is having any data than i want to delete entire row . Have tried with countA function but failed. Kindly Help

Comment: Is the last cell always "H1", or is this dynamic?

Comment: no its not dynamic last cell will always be H1

Comment: This has been asked multiple times, just search the site.

Answer (score 0):

If "H1" is always your last cell, try this:

```
If Range("H1").Value = "" then
    Range("H1").EntireRow.Delete
End if
```

if you go through it with a loop:

```
If Range("H" & row & "").Value = "" then
    Range("H" & row & "").EntireRow.Delete
End if
```